# QTreeView: how to abort selection change

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I have a `QTreeView` in my widget. When an item is selected in  the view, I have
a signal handler that updates a series of information widgets in a detail window
about the selected item. The user can then edit the item details and commit the
changes back to the model.

If the data in the details view has been edited when this selection change
happens, I present a confirmation dialog to the user before replacing the data
when a new item is selected. If the user cancels, I want to set the selection of
the tree back to what it was before.

I have my slot connected like so:

```
auto selection_model = treeview->selectionModel();
connect(
    selection_model, &QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged,
    this, &Editor::on_tree_selection_changed
)
```

Inside my slot, the code is structured as follows:

```
void on_tree_selection_changed(QModelIndex const& index, QModelIndex const& previous)
{
    if(not confirm_editor_discard()) 
    { 
        // user does not want to override current edits
        log.trace("cancel item selection change");
        using SF = QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags;
        auto sm = treeview->selectionModel();
        sm->setCurrentIndex(previous, SF::SelectCurrent | SF::Rows);
    }
    else
    {
        // user wants to discard, so update the details view.
        log.trace("discard pending edits");
        set_details_from_model(index);
    }
}
```

However, the setting of the current index back to the previous does not seem to
affect the TreeView; it still displays the newly selected item as selected, and
the interface becomes non-coherent since the item displayed in the details is
not the one shown as selected in the tree.

The intended behaviour is to re-select the previously selected item, as if no
new selection was made at all.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `QTreeView` ignores any updates from the selection model while the `currentChanged` slot is being called.

The solution here was to call the slot as a `QueuedConnection`, so the `connect` line would look like this:

```
connect(
    selection_model, &QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged,
    this, &Editor::on_tree_selection_changed,
    Qt::QueuedConnection // <-- connection must be queued. 
)
```

This will ensure that the change in selection of the selection model will not happen directly inside a slot call.

Comment: It can’t do much else: after all, your slot code is running then. But what really happened was that you got bitten by writing pseudosynchronous code. The dialog handler belongs in a slot! Had you done that, you’d never have run into that problem.

Comment: Can you run a modal dialog non-synchronous?

Comment: Yes, you can. Modality is just a special state of the UI, it doesn't change the asynchronous behavior of it. Doing special tricks like running pseudosynchronous code is just sweeping the problem under the rug.